# Further automating Ubuntu-Nginx-WordPress server environment establishment script?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, nginx, automation

With the following script I create a Ubuntu-Nginx-WordPress based environment. How could I further automate (hence shorten) the amount of code in that script?

```
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -y && apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
ufw enable && ufw allow 22/tcp 25/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp 9000/tcp
apt-get install zip unzip tree unattended-upgrades sshguard postfix nginx python-certbot-nginx mysql-server php-fpm php-mysql php-mbstring php-mcrypt -y
sed -i "s/# gzip_/gzip_/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i "s/max_size = .M/max_size = 200M/g" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

### Notes

- I'm open to use Tasksel.
- I don't want to use either Ansible or Salt as both seem to me overwhelming and complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Muru, please remove that link. I deleted the question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tell `curl` to directly write to `/usr/local/bin/wp`:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar > /usr/local/bin/wp && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp
```

[`add-apt-repository` in 17.04 and newer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) has a `-u` option, allowing you to skip the explicit `apt-get update`:

```
-u, --update After adding the repository, update the package cache with
             packages from this repository (avoids need to apt-get update)
```

You can also combine the `apt-get upgrade` and `install` steps:

```
apt-get upgrade zip unzip tree unattended-upgrades sshguard postfix nginx python-certbot-nginx mysql-server php-fpm php-mysql php-mbstring php-mcrypt -y
```

Combined:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -yu
ufw enable && ufw allow 22/tcp 25/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp 9000/tcp
apt-get upgrade zip unzip tree unattended-upgrades sshguard postfix nginx python-certbot-nginx mysql-server php-fpm php-mysql php-mbstring php-mcrypt -y
sed -i 's/# gzip_/gzip_/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i 's/max_size = .M/max_size = 200M/g' /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
sed -i 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar > /usr/local/bin/wp && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp
```